# How do you set Chart Axis labels to relative minutes?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a Chart (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`) which has a number of points which have `DateTime` as the X-Axis. 
I am trying to label the x-axis as relative minutes from the start time, like this picture.

My data is added in a loop like this

```
     chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(point.timestamp, point.value);
```

[image: How the chart should look.]

So far I have this code...(which displays hours and minutes)

```
        // Y-Axis
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

        // X-Axis
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = startTime.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = startTime.AddMinutes(25).ToOADate();
```

I cannot figure out the correct LabelStyle Format to get the display I want. 
I have looked at CustomLabels but this doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be great. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Why not convert a `point.timestamp` to the *relative minute* when you add points?

Comment: I did think of that, and if it's not possible that is what I'll do. But I wanted to add  a mouseover event which would display the values of the chart in labels to the user - including the actual datetime value.